# How do you say: "You sound German" in Russian?

Tags: перевод

I know that "это звучит ужасно' means "that sounds terrible" but how do you say: "You sound German/Russian/American" et cetera in Russian?

Answer (score 14):

People don't generally "sound" in Russian; using **звучать** here would suggest an absurd notion that the speaker themself is a sound. **Ты говоришь как немец** (male) / **немка** (female) is one way to say it, but it's ambiguous in that it can also be understood as "you say the kinds of things a German would say". You can rephrase it more directly as **У тебя немецкий акцент** (or **немецкий выговор**), but that doesn't quite have the tentativeness of "You sound German". What I would probably say in this situation is something like: **А ты немец/немка? На слух похоже.**

That may look like a surprising amount of complications but it reflects a cultural difference, in that accents are less of a thing in Russia than they are in the English-speaking world. Most Russians can only very vaguely tell one accent from another, not only foreign, but regional ones as well—which are, in themselves, if not less prominent in Russian then at least something that's less common for people to listen for. Also, as "accents" are a subject that comes with a lot of stereotyping that's only considered offensive when it's invoked on a personal level, "You sound X" is a thing people are more likely to politely shy away from saying—hence the lack of a streamlined expression.

Comment: Great answer, Nikolay! I recently had a similar problem when I described my love for Russian saying something to the effect of: Мне просто нравится, как этот язык звучит. I was told that in Russian, languages don't звучать, only words. Is that accurate?

Comment: @CocoPop That's weird. "Язык звучит" sounds (no pun intended) completely fine to me.

Comment: accents aren't  less a thing in Russia.  In province, you would be easily identified as capital person. I agree that some would shy away from saying so, if they would not want to try to start confrontatiom, but stereotypic identification among masses here is as strong as anywhere else. Diversity of speech is present too, Moscow person would have trouble to understand a russian from north, just like dweller of New England  would easily identify a redneck from south state

Answer (score -1):

In Russian a person can hardly sound like a national language speaker (but not like a person having any emotional state). So there are two different options:

1. If you want to emphasise the non-living object of perception (e.g. the sound of speech), I suggest the same archaic participle forms ending in ***-но***;

***Как (будто) по-немецки сказано / сказал(а).***

like (as if) by-German-MODUS.ADV. said-PAST.P.-NEUT.SG. / said--0-MASC.SG.PAST (FEM.SG.PAST)

1.2. The more simple structures would be:

1.2.1 ***Как (будто) немцем сказано.***

like (as if) a German-MASC.SG.INSTR. said-NEUT.SG.

1.2.2. ***Как (будто) немкой сказано.***

like (as if) a German-FEM.SG.INSTR. said-PAST.P.-NEUT.SG.

1.2.4. ***Как (будто)  немец сказал.***

like (as if) a German-MASC.SG.INSTR. said-0-MASC.SG.PAST

1.2.5. ***Как (будто)  немка сказала.***

like (as if) a German-FEM.SG.INSTR. said-FEM.SG.PAST

1.3. With the verb, you can also add some ***ты*** and ***это***:

1.3.1. ***Ты это как будто немец (немка) сказал(а).***

1.3.2. ***Ты как будто немец (немка) это сказал(а).***

2) Alternatively, if you want to emphasise the verb, you could use the ***звучать*** with ***это***:

***Это звучит как будто / словно (сказано) по-немецки.***

Basically, ***Это звучит*** goes well with any structure from 1.2.

So ***звучать*** and an address a person present at the moment of conversation don't go well together because ***звучать*** implies non-evidentiality, whilest ***ты*** is usually addressed to a visible person present at the moment of a communication.

Comment: You seem to somewhat misunderstand "You sound German". It's hardly something one would say on the basis of a single utterance (as your use of **это** and **сказать** wouild suggest), but rather, after listening to the person talk for a while.

Comment: 'A talk for a while' consists of several utterances. The aspectual and tense systems in English and Russian are different.

Comment: @Manjusri: You seem to be describing the way someone said something "just now," but "You sound German" is a general statement about the way a person says EVERYTHING. I know enough Russian to know that your examples above don't effectively render the feeling or meaning of the English statement.

Comment: @CocoPop Since a person uses the Russian language, everything said just cannot be German. Besides, languages differ and therefore no other suggestion can get 'the feeling or meaning' more efficiently.

Comment: @Manjusri "You sound German" refers to a German accent. Simple as that.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov Nothing is as simple as it seems at a first sight :-D It could also refer to a syntax, or a choice of words, etc.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov to add an insult to injury, a statement akin to "you sound  German" may happen in text chat... where no one actually talks, everyone just type. I really don't know an universal way to translate it to our language, it's a somewhat situational  idiom. E.g., I was told that  I do not sound Russian in chat quite a few times.

Comment: @Swift "You don't sound [your nationality]" is not a nice thing to say, whether or not one subscribes to the currently fashionable notion of "microaggressions".

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov no, you completely wrong. they meant it as  I  don't act stereotypically and  I am unusually good with language. By the way it's person I'm in very good relations for long time now. and conclusions like that you did are actually stereotypically ours, sadly.. I saw it done a lot of time.. even Bondarchuk addressed the problem in his last movie.  We see aggression in everything done and said. It's not only this nation, it's typical to modern culture

Comment: @Swift ...in everything done and said by Germans, you mean?

Comment: @Swift On the contrary, that's exactly what I presume they meant. That is an extremely backhanded compliment that you're entitled to take offence at. Which ironically is a very "Western" idea that I happen to agree with, whereas Russia is all about "they meant it well" and "can't you take a joke". Frankly we could use less of that. (As well as less nepotist mediocrities making movies with sham social messages.)

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov, i know what they meant,  I know them for 15 years from that time. you suppose what they meant, that's the difference. It's offensive only to someone who prides his origin above his abilitity to communicate with people or respect with people. Yes, it may be offensive to texan, to a norvegian or to some russians. Would be offended if someone in russia would tell that you do not sound moscovian, while you are(may be you are not, it is example)? I suppose you might be,  our speech differentl from entire country,  but those who speak in more eloquent  manner cannot be identified.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov  In case I described they could not identify me as a Russian by mistakes and incoherences in speech. Most folks would do mistakes based on their native language patterns if they lack expierence with particular foreign language. Now, do you still think it was an insult?